# Schatten norm inequality

Tags: matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, operator-norms

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices.

Find a lower bound of the $p$-th Schatten norm
$\|(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}$ in terms of Schatten norm of $\|(AA^*+BB^*)\|_{S_q}$ for any relation between $p$ and $q$.

So far, I have obtained the following: For any $\beta\geq 0$, we have
$$
(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\geq \frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^*-\beta BB^*.
$$
I can write now inequality for Schatten norm:

$$
\|(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\geq \|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^*-\beta BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\\
=\|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}(AA^*+BB^*)-\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta} BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}
$$
Since for $x\geq y\geq0$, we have $\sqrt{x-y}\geq \sqrt x-\sqrt y$, we get that above line is
$$
\geq \|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}(AA^*+BB^*)\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}- \|\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta} BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\\
\geq \left(\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta}}\right)\|(AA^*+BB^*)^{1/2}\|_{S_{p}}
$$

Comment: The imperative mode, without any context or illustration of what you have tried, is not exactly inviting.

Comment: @YemonChoi: Thank you. I was not sure if its ok to write long solutions in the questions. I have edited it with my solution. Not sure if I ma correct in it.